# How to get only one value of a json object

Tags: php, json

i have the following output from [my API](http://api.infinicraft/playerStats/?user=infiniman):

```
{
   "profiles":[
      {
         "id":"d2501196e8ed4d729b3727dc64989431",
         "name":"infiniman"
      }
   ],
   "size":1
}
```

But i only want to display the `id` part.

Ho can i do it in PHP?

Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
ini_set("display_errors", false);
$user = $_GET['user'];
$arr = array("name"=>$user, "agent"=>"minecraft");
$data = json_encode($arr);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.mojang.com/profiles/page/1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

if(!($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
echo('[cURL Failure] ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
echo $res;
$username = json_decode($res, true);
echo 'UUID: ' . $username->profiles[0]->id;
?>
```

Comment: this is my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/NpEFTPZ2)

Comment: please don't link to code. It is better to have the code pasted directly here.

Comment: okay sorry I'm new to Stack overflow ;)

Comment: @bansi how do i flag the question as solved?

Comment: @infiniman Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can accept the answer below by clicking the tick mark under the vote buttons on the left of the answer; if it solved your problem.

Comment: in your code you are setting the `assoc` flag to true. so it becomes associative array instead of object. In that case you can use `$username['profiles'][0]['id'];`

Comment: Okay @bansi, i got it to work now take a look @ [link](http://api.infinicraft.net/playerStats/?user=infiniman)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{
   "profiles":[
      {
         "id":"d2501196e8ed4d729b3727dc64989431",
         "name":"infiniman"
      }
   ],
   "size":1
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->profiles[0]->id;
```

Comment: hm how can i make it so that it works automatically even if the name and the id changes?